# How to use different Base Urls in Android App

Tags: java, android

I have number of APIs with common Base Urls in my Android App. There is a login page in my App which has a username, password and a login button. After entering the credentials when user single clicks on login button BaseUrl-1 is selected for all APIs whereas if user longpresses the login button, a checkbox appears and when user selects that checkbox and then clicks on login button BaseUrl-2 is selected for all APIs in my App.

The BaseUrl is present in the utility class. My problem is that if my App is running in Background and I clear it from Background and again open my App, the Base Url gets lost i.e, I get NullPointerException if any Api gets hit because BaseUrl is null.

The code which I implemented is:

```
public class Activity_Login extends Activity implements OnLongClickListener 
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    checkBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btnSubmit.setOnLongClickListener(this);
}
public void onButtonClick(View v) {

if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
            Utility.WHICH_URL = 2;
        }else {
            Utility.WHICH_URL = 1;
        }
        Utility.URL();
         url = Utility.BASE_URL;
            if (username.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                showToast("Please enter User Name");
            } else if (password.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                showToast("Please enter password");
            } else {
                try {
                    String encodedUsername = URLEncoder.encode(username
                            .getText().toString().trim(), "UTF-8");
                    String encodedPassword = URLEncoder.encode(password
                            .getText().toString().trim(), "UTF-8");
                    NetworkOperation operation = new NetworkOperation(this);
                    operation.execute("GetLogin", encodedUsername,
                            encodedPassword);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(Activity_Login.this,
                            "Enter valid credentials.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
}
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

    checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    return true;
}

}
```

My Utility class is:

```
public class Utility {

public static String BASE_URL1= null;
public static  String BASE_URL= null;
 public static final String URL() {
if(WHICH_URL==1){

     BASE_URL1="http://live.net/api.php";

}else if(WHICH_URL==2){
     BASE_URL1="http://staging.net/api.php";

}

BASE_URL  = BASE_URL1;
return BASE_URL;

}
}
```

How to solve this problem??

Comment: better to save URL in `Preferences`

Comment: I've used sharedPref, but its strange that sharedPref data too gets lost..